# MYSQL Query NOT EQUAL GROUP BY still display unwanted result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm trying to get the right query for the following case

For example i have an Election name 'Election A' and have two candidates B & C.

If candidate B already nominate in the election, candidate B cannot vote & view the election

But with my current query it still display to candidate B and C. Can someone help with my query?

```
SELECT * 
    FROM candidates 
    LEFT JOIN positions 
        ON positions.id=candidates.position_id 
    WHERE candidates.candidate_id != '".$voter['voters_id']."' 
    GROUP BY positions.electiontitle DESC
```

candidate_id is an ID that voter use to nominate for any position in the election and it is the same as voter_id

Image of Current Output that still display the unwanted result
[image]

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpQz6.png)

Comment: The query looks fine as far as I can see. It may be an issue, that you are comparing an id (which is most likely an integer) with a string. Does the query return the correct result if you enter a candidate_id by hand (instead of using $voter)? Also you should make sure to escape your parameter before using it in your query.

Comment: Both the id is using same data type (varchar). The query only return 1 ID  but actually i want it to return all id in the same election @DB

Comment: Actual sample data and desired results will help.

Comment: I already edit the post with the sample data, the desired results I want is  I don't want the election "BENDAHARI MPP UTeM" to be display because based on the image of sample data it has the current voter_id =5031. But it still display because it display the data from candidate_id =4411. Hope this help you @Stu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `candidate`
where position_id != (select position_id
                    FROM candidate
                    where candidate_id = 5031)
group by position_id
```

**Try this one mate.**